# Pass the result of a Velocimacro into another Velocimacro

Tags: velocity

I have a few Velocity Macros (Velocimacros) I am using in some of my templates; I would like to pass the results of say a date format macro into another that pads string values. I am trying the following:

```
#pad(#dateFormat("my date"), 30)
```

I am getting an exception saying, "Invalid arg #0 in VM #pad..."

Is it not possible to pass the results of a macro into another macro? I tried to set the value of the "#dateFormat" macro into a variable using:

```
#set ($myParam = #dateFormat("my date"))
```

however, I am getting another exception.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use string interpolation:

```
#pad( "#dateFormat('my date')", 30)
```

Only works for string values, but it's what works. :)